# Making commands so only certain servers can do it

Tags: discord.py

I am wanting only certain servers to be able to use this feature shown below.

I want to know if there is a way to make it so only certain server ids can use this command.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def shittymeme(ctx):
    api = 'https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes'
    response = requests.get(api)
    url = random.choice(response.json()['data']['memes'])
    url = url['url']
    await bot.say( embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x0072ff, title = "Here you go").set_image(url = url))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a whitelist of server ids, you can take advantage of the [`Checks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) feature built into the `commands` extension.

```
whitelist = ["id1", "id2"]

def is_in_server_list(server_list):
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.server.id in server_list
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@is_in_server_list(whitelist)
async def shittymeme(ctx):
    api = 'https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes'
    response = requests.get(api)
    url = random.choice(response.json()['data']['memes'])
    url = url['url']
    await bot.say( embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x0072ff, title = "Here you go").set_image(url = url))
```